# Micro service architecture : Solving complex queries owned by particular service

Tags: node.js, microservices, mongodb

I am working micro service architecture and figuring out what is the best way to get complex data from a micro service. 
So for example : Let's say micro service A is owning data based on any CRUD operations, there are X,Y,Z services which requires some sort of aggregated info and conditional info from micro service A, what is the best way to go implement it ?

1. One could be writing methods in A which generate realtime data and send back to other micro services
2. Second could sending events from micro service A to other micro services to update their view of data, and reflect that back to other micro services

FYI I am using mongoDB as data base and node.js as application.

Comment: both have advantages and disadvantages. you'll have to add some info about the users of the service

Comment: Okay, so for example let's say I am creating social network backend system, in which I am creating a review microservice. Now there are other services for example customer profile / avg review on platform in country  etc and customer profile will only get those reviews  which are from last 20 days. This is an example of conditional plus aggregated query.

Comment: Id go with 1 in that case, as you have many users and the data is not time sensitive

Comment: Won't the expose problem of one micro service becoming bottleneck for such data ? If review service goes down, other will be getting impacted by it, also single service will have to expose hell lot of methods to scale out based on various use cases.

Comment: Why should review service be worried about, how other services are consuming its data ? Like why it should write logic for profile getting reviews info in a particular order with constraint text limit etc. ?

Comment: no, yes but that happens anyway, it doesnt have to but there might be benefits, because that might mean less data being passed around and hence a faster service.

Comment: Okay, in my view service is faster if it's scalable in terms of use cases and defined ownership. In case data is too much to send we can look for CQRS, but CQRS also proposes to maintain two models, in which to expose query model, you either have to expose APIs or you will have to share it with all micros service which is breaking micro service architecture. Basically I am not too convinced with having functional methods at micro service end to handle for all the use cases we have. It will make micro service fragile and up for breakage with too many dependencies.

Comment: I think you should write a new question with real examples.. Generally your services should have specific Methods rather than taking any query. It makes them faster and more testable. But this is a separate question, you cant get around having those functions with your push message option. you are just calling the function from a different place. If you have a small number of things to update, say a log then I would use 2. but with a large number of things, say everyone's profile, its impractical. you'll be updating profiles no one is looking at and replicating the same data all over the place

Comment: Sorry, if I have given less description, but would close this thread with my suggestions, findings and brain storming.

Answer (score -1):

So basically there are following ways to sharing data that a particular domain (from domain driven design world) owns. Which is :

1. Functional methods
2. CQRS : Commands query responsibility segregation where query model sits separately to honour any query for particular data present in a domain.
3. Event streaming : Any particular service needs to publish some kind of events which will allow dependent services to consume then to update their own view or interpretation.
4. Event sourcing : Have everything on event bus which is some sort of persistent event logs and all micro services derive data out of it through filtration and projection.

In any micro service world, best approaches are either combination of CQRS and event streaming or event sourcing.

I will personally go with CQRS with event streaming for now, seems stable and feasible solution for now. I am leaving respective details upto you guys to figure out. Suggestions are respected, and please correct if people think otherwise.